# How do I overcome the XHR FF POST size limit?

Tags: ajax, post, size, limit, xmlhttprequest

My XHR POST REQUEST is cut off. When I try to reload my page information is missing. Firebugs sends following message:

> Firebug request size limit has been reached by Firebug.

My question is: What are my options?

1. Would it work if I declare the content.length in the header?
2. I added a line to my apache config file and restarted it: LimitRequestBody 0
3. I increased the size of transfer files in mysql config file

Or it is a browser issue?

The only solution I could think of was to cut the data in pieces and transmit the array one by one but I don't like this idea. The content length is 91691 according to firebug.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to modify Firebug settings. In browser's address bar go to **about:config**, then look for option `extensions.firebug.netDisplayedPostBodyLimit`.

You should increase its value in order to see non truncated requests. Set it to **65535** for example.

Here you can find many other Firebug options you may want to change: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences